# How to make C# aware of the nullability of convenient properties?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Consider this code snippet, which has no nullable warnings.

```
public class Foo {
    public string Property { get; } = "Some String";
}

public class Bar {
    [DisallowNull]
    public Foo? Foo { get; private set; }
    
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Foo))]
    public void MyMethod() {
        Foo = new Foo();
        
        // After setting Foo, I use Foo.Property in some way
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Property);
    }
}
```

Since in my real code, I use `Foo.Property` after setting `Foo` *a lot*, I wanted to add a "convenient property" to `Bar` that returns it directly, so that I can access it with a shorter name (`Foo` is actually a rather long name in my real code):

```
// in Bar
public string? Property => Foo?.Property;

// ...
// Now I can do:
Console.WriteLine(Property);
```

However, now `Bar.Property` is nullable, even in a place where `Foo` is definitely not null (such as just after setting `Foo`). So when I use `Property` in a place where null is not allowed, the compiler gives me warnings.

I thought what I needed is to annotate `Property` with something like `NotNullIfMemberNotNull(nameof(Foo))`, but after looking it up, [this attribute is only proposed, and doesn't exist yet](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49741).

How can I work around this?

Comment: When you say "convenient properties", do you mean "auto-implemented properties"?

Comment: @Llama No, I mean a property that just returns a property of another property, like how `Property` in `Bar` returns `Foo.Property`. Basically, it's purpose is to shorten the name, so that I don't have to write `Foo.` every time.

Comment: Regarding foo - why do you allow null (`foo?`) but decorate it with `[DisallowNull]`. Shouldn't it be `[DisallowNull] public Foo foo { get; private set; }`  instead ? (without the "Elvis" operator) Likewise with your property `public string? Property` - why do you use the `?` operator here?

Comment: @Matt Because it is not initialised in the constructor (it doesn't make sense to do that in my use case), but null should not be assigned to it. Essentially, `Foo` here is very similar to the example of `ReviewComment` described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#preconditions-allownull-and-disallownull).

Comment: I see - so you make it nullable to indicate it's not properly initialized, but you want to disallow null in general.

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `MemberNotNull` is a post condition that only signals to callers that the specified member will not be null after the member returns. It will not help you within the method itself unfortunately.

I understand you're using a simplification of a larger pattern, but one way I would suggest rewriting `MyMethod` is:

```cs
public void MyMethod() {
    var foo = new Foo();
    Foo = foo;
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Property);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One workaround I came up with is make both `Foo` and `Property` have backing fields. In the setter of `Foo`, also set `Property`. This way, we can add the `MemberNotNull` attribute to the setter of `Foo`.

```
private Foo? foo;

[DisallowNull]
public Foo? Foo { 
    get => foo;
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Property))]
    private set {
        foo = value;
        Property = value.Property;
    }
}

public string? Property { get; private set; }
```

However, this isn't very general. It only works because `Foo` just happens to be marked as `DisallowNull`.